# How to fix broken pattern match for numbers with sed in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am on Mac and I have a command that outputs formatted json. I need to zero out a field and consider using `sed` for it. Below is a MVCE to highlight the problem:

```bash
$ echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/"mtime": *[0-9]/"mtime": 0/g'
"mtime": 0234, # <-- this is expected but need to zero out the entire number
```

```bash
                                            adding + to capture the entire number
                                                v
$ echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/"mtime": *[0-9]+/"mtime": 0/g'
"mtime": 1234, # <-- this isn't expected


                                             escaping +
                                                 v
$ echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/"mtime": *[0-9]\+/"mtime": 0/g'
"mtime": 1234, # <-- this isn't expected
```

[image]

The regex is straight forward but still doesn't work as expected.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/"mtime":[^0-9][0-9]\([0-9]*\)/"mtime": 0\1/g'` works for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, it returns `"mtime": 0234,`

Comment: Then what is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Jetchisel! I incorrectly described the expected value. Instead I expect the entire number to be 0.

Comment: `echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/"mtime": *[0-9]\{1,\}/"mtime": 0/g'`

Comment: `echo \"mtime\": 1234, | sed 's/\([^ ]*\) [0-9]\{1,\}/\1 0/g'`

Comment: `echo \"mtime\": 1234foobar, | sed 's/\([^ ]*\) [0-9]\{1,\}/\1 0/g'`

Comment: The `+` is a _GNU_ extension afaik. It is not defined on  standard/posix `sed`/

Comment: The trailing `g` can be omitted  though.

Comment: Thanks so much! `\{1,\}` did the trick! I could accept that as an answer.

Comment: Glad I could help, but I'll take a pass on posting an answer since there might be another duplicate somewhere. See `man 7 regex` if available.

Comment: If you use `sed` with extended regex syntax (`-E`) then `+` should work as is. Otherwise you can use `\+` instead of `+`. Another, more verbose alternative is `[0-9][0-9]*`.